# jsonb: nested serializing not called by Jsonb

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jsonb-api

New Tag request: java-ee-8

It's got a new feature, called jsonb. With jsonb, I cannot get nested serialization working. See bold printed below.

So, I wrote a jaxrs-application. This application's got  a messagebodywriter using jsonb:

```
final JsonbConfig defaultConfig = new JsonbConfig()
        .withFormatting(Boolean.TRUE)
        .withNullValues(Boolean.TRUE)
        .withSerializers(
            new QueryParamEntrySerializer(),
            new ApiResponseDtoSerializer())
        .withAdapters(new ResponseStatusJsonbAdapter());
    final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(defaultConfig);
```

ApiResponseDto is like following:

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonbTypeSerializer(ApiResponseDtoSerializer.class)
public interface ApiResponseDto {

  ResponseStatus status();

  String message();

  Optional<? extends Object> data();
}
```

ResponseStatus is an enumm and gets serialized via the above TypeAdapter just fine.
For this class I wrote the ApiResponseDtoSerializer.

```
@Provider
public class ApiResponseDtoSerializer implements JsonbSerializer<ImmutableApiResponseDto> {

  @Override
  public void serialize(
      final ImmutableApiResponseDto obj,
      final JsonGenerator generator,
      final SerializationContext ctx) {
    generator.writeStartObject();
    ctx.serialize("status", obj.status(), generator);
    ctx.serialize("data", obj.data(), generator);
    ctx.serialize("message", obj.message(), generator);
    generator.writeEnd();
  }

}
```

Now the Optional data() shall contain an ImmutableSet of QueryParamEntry like this:

```
@Value.Immutable
@JsonbTypeSerializer(ImmutableQueryParamEntrySerializer.class)
public interface QueryParamEntry {
  @Value.Parameter
  String key();

  @Value.Parameter
  Optional<String> value();
}
```

The type adapter is this one:

```
@Provider
public class ImmutableQueryParamEntrySerializer implements JsonbSerializer<ImmutableQueryParamEntry> {

  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ImmutableQueryParamEntrySerializer.class);

  @Override
  public void serialize(
      final ImmutableQueryParamEntry obj,
      final JsonGenerator generator,
      final SerializationContext ctx) {
    generator.writeStartObject();
    LOG.debug("Writing: key = [{}].", obj.key());
    ctx.serialize("key", obj.key(), generator);
    ctx.serialize("value", obj.value(), generator);
    generator.writeEnd();
  }

}
```

The final output is:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "key": null,
            "value": null
        }
    ],
    "message": "Returning query param values."
}
```

**As you can see, the nested serialization did not work.** Jsonb seems to find the correct type (because otherwise it wouldn't serialize an object at all). But even the log statement from my SerializerClass is never called.

Btw: You need Guava 22 and immutables.github.io to compile this code, and slf4j obviously:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON-P API -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.json.bind/javax.json.bind-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.json.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
      <artifactId>value</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Re your request for a new tag **java-ee-8**, it is there now.

Comment: Also, what are you using for the the serialization? (i.e. What code is implementing SerializationContext?)

Comment: @skomisa i was using the implementation which ships with openliberty.

Comment: OK, thanks. I might try that since [I am also having deserialization problems](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/issues/118), but I am using Yasson.

Comment: FYI OpenLiberty ships Yasson as its JSON-B implementation, so I would expect behavior to be the same whether you are running in OpenLiberty or directly using Yasson. AFAIK the immutables lib generates some classes automatically, and I don't think that has been tested well with JSON-B/Yasson. If you could include the generated classes that would be helpful to determine the problem.

Comment: I created this issue: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/issues/164

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what it takes to make it work.

I got rid of the custom Serializers. As mentioned in my comment, they are broken before the unreleased version 1.0.3 anyway.

Instead, rename your methods to `getStatus()`, `getMessage()` and `getData()` (notice the `get`-Prefix).
For `getData();`, return just an `Optional<Object>`, not `Optional<? extends Object>`. Otherwise, immutables will refuse the special treatment of Optional.

After that, all just worked nicely.